# Break values in one column into multiple rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to explode values belonging to one id into multiple rows.

```
category_id          subcategory_ids 
    123                    111
                           123
                           333
    465                    444
                           555
```

The result I am trying to achieve should look like below-

```
category_id          subcategory_ids 
    123                    111
    123                    123
    123                    333
    465                    444
    465                    555
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT category_id, subcategory_ids
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(subcategory_ids) subcategory_ids
```

Comment: I find it so interesting that people don't seem to be interested in how the code works - I mean lateral joins with arrays that got turned into table format is not a widely known concept, right?